# Using MvvmCross in xamarin.android,how to Access UI object from ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I‘m a beginer who uses MvvmCross for the Xamarin.Android.I try to realize the function like 'click the button and show a dialog to say hello'.

When I use the way which sets ViewModel object to Activity object's DataContext to bind,I can pass UI object directly (or using Interface indirectly).In this way,I can access UI object to show a dialog.

In another way likes the offical demo, bing the UI object and ViewModel automatically,how can I show the dialog?The auto bing code like this

public class App:MvxApplication { public App() { Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new MvxAppStart()); } }

[Activity(Label = "MvvmC_TutorialActivity")] public class MvvmC_TutorialActivity : MvxActivity 
{ 
   ............. 
}

Comment: Your question is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks！

I slove the problem!I can pass the UI object in 'MvxActivity's OnViewModelSet'.

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_Tip);//pass UI object here
}
```